# What is the point of talking about linear independence for 1 element

Tags: linear-algebra

Let ${w*(80/27,-76/27,-31/27)} $ be the solution set of a homogeneous system of linear equations.

The statement to be decided if it's true or false, is this:

> The solution set of the given system, contains at least one linearly
>   independent element

As I got, using wolfram with this query:

> linear independence (1,2*w)

(and got this)

> (1, 2 w) is linearly independent

What is the point of talking about linear independence for 1 element?

Also, could the statement be false, due to the fact that the linearly independent is **only one** and **not at least one**?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of linear independence holds for one element as it does for any other number of elements. An element $v$ is linearly independent if $cv=0$ with $c$ a scalar implies $c=0$. Thus the only linearly dependent element is $0$.

Comment: @Chris: You're welcome!